# A Multi-leveled Gaming Concept

Tags: riddle, video-games

*Many games runs on me, 

yet I'm found in a game.

To the game's family,

I lend also my name.*

*So go run and climb,

and jump with abandon,

but remember that I'm

the thing that you stand on.*

Please tell me what I am, and explain why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're...

> a platform!
>  Platform is a word for the system a game runs on - PC, Wii, XBox, Playstation, etc.
>  Platforms are also common in games like Mario and Metroid.
>  Those games are called platformers.

Comment: That is... correct!